# How to fix print message issues in fabric

Tags: python-3.x, fabric

I am using `Fabric3 1.12.post1` on `Win10 X64`. I tried the following program,

```
from fabric.operations import local
def platform_user():
   print('Platform: ' + local('echo %OS%'))
   print('Username: ' + local('echo %USERNAME%'))
```

the output is,

```
[localhost] local: echo %OS%
Windows_NT
Platform:
[localhost] local: echo %USERNAME%
my_user_name
Username:

Done.
```

'Platform' and 'Username' did not line up with the outputs, so how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `local` with `capture` (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12/api/core/operations.html):

```
from fabric.operations import local
def platform_user():
    result = local('echo %OS%', capture=True)
    print('Platform: ' + result.stdout)
    result = local('echo %USERNAME%', capture=True)
    print('Username: ' + result.stdout)
```